# VBA - Get website content created dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro which is getting on a particular website, pasting some input, clicking search button and then copying data from search results. 
Unfortunatelly, as far as I understand, search results are prepared dynamically (in JavaScript?) and I don't know how to use any method such as getElementById if I don't know the id.

Here's the website: `https://www.tracktrace.dsv.com/newtracking/login.jsp`
Here's searched in left searchbar content: `DSVAO72630`
And I'm trying to catch anything that's shows up in results, eg. shipment id (on the very top of search results there's SHPTS ID:  `SMMA0019991`). Here's my code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Crawler()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim URL As String
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim searchButton As Object
    Dim searchBar As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    URL = "https://www.tracktrace.dsv.com/newtracking/login.jsp"

    With IE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    Set searchBar = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sid")
    searchBar.Value = "DSVAO72630"
    Set searchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("SEARCH")
    searchButton.Item(0).Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Crawler()
    Dim IE As Object, HTMLDoc As Object, searchButton As Object
    Dim searchBar As Object, tbl As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Dim Ar As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    URL = "https://www.tracktrace.dsv.com/newtracking/login.jsp"

    With IE
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    Set searchBar = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sid")
    searchBar.Value = "DSVAO72630"
    Set searchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementsByName("SEARCH")
    searchButton.Item(0).Click

    Wait 2

    Set tbl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(2)

    Ar = Split(tbl.Cells(1, 2).outertext, vbNewLine)

    For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
        If InStr(1, Ar(i), "SHPTS ID:") Then
            Debug.Print Trim(Split(Ar(i), ":")(1))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    IE.Quit

    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem! I'm just curious... How did you know that this particular table with data which I am looking for is a table number 2 (or 3? is it counted starting from 0?)? I am asking about `Set tbl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(2)` line of code.

Comment: I debugged it and found it out :)